# Modifying $post->post_content in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, filtering, shortcode

I'm using a template that seems to be outputting `$post->post_content` in the search page.

I maintain a plugin that uses a non-standard shortcode format and I'm trying to find out **how can I filter `$post->post_content` before it gets displayed** because currently my shortcode is not getting covered (again, not using the Shortcode API).

This has me stumped. Any help, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [`the_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post) action hook, that allows to modify the post object immediately after being queried and setup:

```
add_action('the_post', function($post, $query){

    // do whatever you want to $post, for example:
    $post->post_content = str_replace('{YOUR_SHORTCODE}', 'WHATEVER', $post->post_content);

}, 10, 2);
```